# about the QT class QFileSystemModel

Tags: qt

I'd like to use the class QFileSystemModel to show my file system in QTreeView.
But when I set thr root path in it.I try to get its first filename.It failed.I want to ask that how should I do to get  parent's child info. Thanks

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTreeView view;
    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel(&view);
    model->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
    view.setModel(model);
    view.setCurrentIndex(model->index(model->rootPath()));
    QModelIndex index = model->index(model->rootPath());
    qDebug() << model->fileName(index);   
    qDebug() << model->fileName(index.child(0,0));
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Check out example at http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTreeView_QFileSystemModel_ModelView_MVC.php. You do not need `QModelIndex`.

Comment: thank you for your comment.The example showed above can run well when the node clicked. But if I want  it to run when it loads instread of being clicked. I can get all rootpath's subdirectory because of I have set the rootpath.Now I want to get the way of accessing its subfiles and subdirectory when the tree loading

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
model->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView(splitter);
tree->setModel(model);
```

`splitter`is parent Dialog, which view will reside in.

Comment: thank you for your comment.The example showed above can run well when the node clicked. But if I want it to run when it loads instread of being clicked. I can get all rootpath's subdirectory because of I have set the rootpath.Now I want to get the way of accessing its subfiles and subdirectory when the tree loading .

Comment: Do not thank, if you found something useful in my answer/comment, then upvote it.